# How to: create executable from inside the c# program with variable content?

Tags: c#, executable, on-the-fly

Here's the example of problem: I make an addition to SQL DB, and want my program at the moment, when I got positive response - to create an executable, which deletes entry based on it's GUID.
Is it possible to create an executable from inside the C# code with variable content?
One way that I see a resolution for this problem - "CSharpCodeProvider" plus creating a .cs file and compiling it, but not quite sure.
Is this a correct variant or are there any other variants?

UPD: A bit wider description.
Main code, after several authentifications lets user to add content to database, adds GUID for that info and a security token for access. Generated EXE uses security token for authentification and deletes from DB data based on generated earlier GUID.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a sensible thing to do - if you're deleting an entry from SQL then there should be no need to generate c# code - at most, call precompiled code with parameters. If you're deleting something from the disk, there will be a command-line utility. Please feel free to share the whole problem - not just a candidate solution.

Comment: OK. Main code, after several authentifications lets user to add content to database, adds GUID for that info and a security token for access. Generated EXE uses security token for authentification and deletes from DB data based on generated earlier GUID.